# Microsoft Graph returned ErrorInvalidUser for valid user

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have an application that reads users mail messages. I made the same call multiple times in a row. The middle attempt i received an error indicated that the requested user was invalid. I know this to not be true since i had requests before and after this request pass with the same parameters.

```
{"error": {"code": "ErrorInvalidUser", "message": "The requested user 'scrubbed' is invalid.", "innerError": {"date": "2020-10-05T14:42:17", "request-id": "30ede436-594b-4146-b06f-42ceff3201db", "client-request-id": "30ede436-594b-4146-b06f-42ceff3201db"}}}
```

I am wondering what conditions can cause this error. Would an expired oauth token cause this error. Or does this error really reflect that this user no longer exists? (in this case, that would not be an accurate error message).

I did check this page to see if this error is mentioned, but nothing is listed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors

Comment: (1) The above error tells that "The requested user '<user-email>' is invalid" - so make sure the user exists. (2) Check your application logic (3) Make sure your token has the right permission/scope to access the user mailbox (4) Split the application calls into smaller modules and see where it's breaking.

Comment: Did it work for you?